# Reasonable size of data to store in Bundle on onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android

My android app fetches a JSON structure from the net. It's somewhat large, maybe 2,000 characters in length. I need to store it away when my app gets killed so I can recover it quickly. I've tried saving it to an sqlite database, but that takes about 400ms, kind of long. I wonder if it's bad practice to just dump it into the save bundle:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    String jsonString = myObject.toString();
    outState.put("test", jsonString);
}
```

or are we really only supposed to be putting the smallest of items in bundles?

Thanks

Comment: The issue with the Bundle is that it's only usable for short-term storage, i.e. when activities are destroyed and recreated as a result of phone reorientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: I could use that too, and actually my data is more like 60,000 characters in a String. Is that unacceptable for the bundle, or shared preferences?

Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of data =) But if I had to store it, I'd store it in `SharedPreferences` I think. I'm afraid I haven't read any best practices with regards to how much the bundle should hold, so I can't really comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve an object across simple activity changes, try [Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()).

Comment: No, that method purely exists for optimization reasons. You must not rely on it being called, and thus, you still have to store away stuff in onSaveInstanceState().